# Fixed axes in dojo spider chart

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

Is there a possibility to have fixed axes for the dojo spider chart? I want every axis showing a fixed value range.
Can I prevent dojo from calculating the scale?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. I just added two series to the spider chart: One series indicates the minimum and the other one the maximum of the desired range.

After chart.render() I removed these series again and added my legend...works very well for me :)

Comment: That works, but it seems to break my selectable legend. Now clicking the checkboxes won't selectively hide each series.

Answer (score 0):

not yet (or you would have to patch it) but there are discussions around that. See: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14583#comment:5

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. The autoscaling axes are causing me all kinds of problems. It make it impossible to display just one data series, and I have other data series that have one variable that's the same for every series and that screws up the whole plot. I don't know why you can't just addAxis, but apparently the spider plot doesn't use those axes.